# odoo - 9 how to install custom module in odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo-9

I have installed odoo - 9 in my local , I cannot able to see my custom module in update module list. I have activated "Developer Mode" even though it is not appearing in my module list. I also updated the module list, Can anybody guide me to install "Custom Module"  .

Comment: Where you have put that custom module and who can access to it ?

Answer (score 1):

To install a new module in Odoo you have to :

1. Take a acces right to your new module : `chmod -R 755 custom_module`
2. In admin user activate external carctirstique
3. restart the service `service odoo restart`
4. Update module list